# How to fix decreasing time of spawning object on LevelValue change

Tags: c#, android-studio

have a script with spawning objects , I want to DECREASE spawnRate when LevelValue go up.

so I did function that is Increasing LevelValue every 10seconds (and that works fine)

but when I try to put that in other script to decrease value, althought it is decreasing it, but not when LevelValue change on the screen.

It's kind of rapidly decreasing it, first 10 second, than 8, 6,4,2,1, etc. etc.

can't understand what I'm doing wrong, as if LevelValue act the same than something is wrong, but here it works, but in other place doesn't.

am I missing something guys? Hope it's not any stupid mistake.

My function to show LevelValue on the screen:

```
public class TimeLevel : MonoBehaviour
{


public static int levelValue = 1;
Text level;

void Start()
{
    level = GetComponent<Text>();
}


void Update()
{
    level.text = "Level:" + levelValue;
}
}
```

My function to increase LevelValue:

```
public class TimerTEST : MonoBehaviour
{

private float timerSpeed = 10f;

private float elapsed;




void Update()
{

    elapsed += Time.deltaTime;

    if (elapsed >= timerSpeed)
    {
        elapsed = 0f;
        TimeLevel.levelValue += 1;
    }


}
}
```

My spawning object function with decrease time:

```
public class SPawnHorizontal : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject enemy1;



public float spawnTime1 = 1.0f;
public float minSpawnTime = 0.3f;
public float decreaseSpawnTime;


private Vector2 screenBounds;


void Start()
{
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(new 
Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    StartCoroutine(EnemyWave1());


private void spawnEnemy1()
{
    GameObject a1 = Instantiate(enemy1) as GameObject;
    a1.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x * - 20, 
Random.Range(-20,20 ));

    switch (TimeLevel.levelValue)
    {

        case 2:

            spawnTime1 -= decreaseSpawnTime;
            break;

        case 3:

            spawnTime1 -= decreaseSpawnTime;
            break;

        case 4:

            spawnTime1 -= decreaseSpawnTime;
            break;


    }
   }
```